Shift data in a holoviews overlay
My code creates an overlay by calculating multiple hv.Curve() together. The issue is, this takes quite some time (in total something like 5000 lines) - around a minute, and its for a webinterface, so waiting that long is just not good.
But: the grid it creates is always the same, except shifted along the X-Axis (Y is sensor value, X is time, and as the data was acquired at different point in times, the X is flexible between samples).
Is it possible to create a X=0 based overlay, and then just shift it to new coordinates? I have not found anything like this yet, but I cannot image it being hard to maybe manually set the X coordinates of that overlay, or call a function to set an offset or similar, but I have not been able to find that.
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

points_1 = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]
points_2 = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i) + np.cos(0.2*i)) for i in range(100)]
curve_1 = hv.Curve(points_1)
curve_2 = hv.Curve(points_2)

overlay = curve_1 * curve_2
# overlay = overlay + 3 (what to do here to shift the graph 3 units to the right?)
overlay

